# Trouble Proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}(n)^2}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)^4}{\zeta(2s)}$

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series, euler-product

I am running into considerable trouble trying to prove the identity in the question. I figure the solution will come from Euler-products, so here was my attempt. I want to show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d(n)^2}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s)^4}{\zeta(2s)},
$$
where
$$
d(n):=\sum_{d\mid n} 1.
$$

First for prime $p$, $d(p)=2$ and $d(p^n)=n+1$, 
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d(n)^2}{n^s} &= \prod_p \left(1 + \frac{d(p)^2}{p^s} + \frac{d(p^2)^2}{p^{2s}} + \frac{d(p^3)^2}{p^{3s}} + \cdots\right) \\
&= \prod_p \left(1+\frac{2^2}{p^s} + \frac{3^2}{p^{2s}}+\frac{4^2}{p^{3s}}+\cdots \right) \\
&= \prod_p \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{p^{(n-1)s}} \\
&= \prod_p \frac{p^{2s}(p^s+1)}{(p^s-1)^3}, \qquad \text{according to Wolfram Alpha}
\end{align*}
$$
Here is where I get stuck. My next thought was if we look at what the Euler-product form of $\frac{\zeta(s)^4}{\zeta(2s)}$ we might be able to see the connection.
$$
\frac{\zeta(s)^4}{\zeta(2s)} = \prod_p\frac{\left(1-\frac1{p^s}\right)^4}{\left(1-\frac1{p^{2s}}\right)} = \prod_p \frac{p^{-4s}-4p^{-3s}+6p^{-2s}-4p^{-s}+1}{1-p^{-2s}}
$$
but I see no way to transform this product into the one we have derived.

From here I have no clue how to proceed. I also know that Ramanujan's identity 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma_a(n)\sigma_b(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(s-a)\zeta(s-b)\zeta(s-a-b)}{\zeta(2s-a-b)}
$$
would solve this for me, but I'd like to do it directly for this specific case to get used to manipulating products like this. Any hints on how to continue?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) -- this is where I go when my denominator is a product.  I note that the divisor function, $d$, has $d = 1 \ast 1$.

Comment: @EricTowers I am familiar with Dirichlet convolution, but I've only seen it in the context of multiplying two Dirichlet series. Do you mean that there is a way to use it here or that I should restart with the Dirichlet series representations of $\zeta(s)^4$ and $\frac{1}{\zeta(2s)}$ and multiply them that way?

Comment: Yes, prime-wise is smart. And, also, not _positive_ powers of $p$ or $p^s$, but _negative_... and then things turn out as sanely as we can hope. Of course, there's Estermann's example of $d(n)^3$, which (provably) cannot be re-arranged to anything elementary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually,
$$\frac{\zeta(s)^4}{\zeta(2s)} = \prod_p\frac{\left(1-\frac1{p^{2s}}\right)}
{\left(1-\frac1{p^s}\right)^4}.$$
Then
$$\prod_p\frac{\left(1-\frac1{p^{2s}}\right)}
{\left(1-\frac1{p^s}\right)^4}
=\frac{p^{2s}(p^{2s}-1)}{(p^s-1)^4}=\frac{p^{2s}(p^s-1)(p^s+1)}{(p^s-1)^4}
=\frac{p^{2s}(p^s+1)}{(p^s-1)^3}
$$
etc.

Comment: Wow.... I spent the better part of an hour staring at this. Thank you... :/